# Spring Data MongoDb query on nested JSON

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

```
Can anyone tell how to query on nested JSON structure of MongoDB by using Spring Data JPA repository?
JSON Structure:
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7469c6cb96da2a63a5f910"), 
    "_class" : "org.ramyam.eis.model.cube.CubeDataServiceStorageModel", 
    "cubeDataServiceConfigModel" : {
        "Id" : NumberInt(9), 
        "cubeName" : "TestCube", 
        "dataSourceName" : "UserProfile_PNCA,Transaction_PNCA", 
        "dataSourceCount" : "2", 
        "joinCriteria" : "UserProfile_PNCA join Transaction_PNCA on (UserProfile_PNCA.City_V=Transaction_PNCA.City_V)", 
        "filterCriteria" : "", 
        "dimensions" : "UserProfile_PNCA.City_V as PNCA.City_V,UserProfile_PNCA.Country_Code_V as Country_Code_V,Transaction_PNCA.ProductCategory_V as ProductCategory_V", 
        "periodDimensions" : "Transaction_PNCA.OrderDate_D as OrderDate_D", 
        "otherDimensions" : "tenantId_V", 
        "periodExtracts" : "Year_P,Quarter_P,Month_P,Week_P", 
        "measures" : "count(Transaction_PNCA.OrderID_N) as OrderID_N,max(Transaction_PNCA.Sales_F) as Sales_F", 
        "otherMeasures" : "", 
        "outputStorageType" : "Mongodb", 
        "outputConnectionString" : "mongodb://azure:azure123@192.168.1.28:27017/enliven_cube_azure_dev?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1", 
        "statusFlag" : "I", 
        "userName" : "priyanka.utwal@ramyamlab.com", 
        "tenantId" : "GOE", 
        "dataServiceCode" : "GOE_TestCube"
    }, 
    "port" : NumberInt(0), 
    "path" : "", 
    "contentType" : "", 
    "serviceMethod" : "", 
}

Model:

@Document(collection = CollectionConstants.COLLECTION_EIS_DATA_SERVICE_DETAILS)
public class DataServiceConfigurationModel extends DataServiceMasterConfigurationModel{
    private String hostname;
    private int port;
    private String path;
    private String contentType;
    private String serviceMethod;
    private String activeFlag;
    private String dbType;
    private String dataServiceCode;
    private String dataSourceId;
    private String dataSourceName;
    private String dataSourceType;
    private String from;
    private String dsName;
    private List<Dimension> selectD;
    private List<Measure> selectM;
    private SystemParameters systemParameters;
    private List<DSJoin> join;
    private CubeDataServiceConfigDTO cubeDataServiceConfigModel;
}
```

And try to query on cubeDataServiceConfigModel.cubeName nested JOSN object.SO,please let me know how to write a method in Springdata JPA to query on nested JSON.
In mongoclient we can query through cubeDataServiceConfigModel.cubeName like this.But,in JPA ?

Comment: can you show us an example of your json structure data?

Comment: you should provide more details. You json strucutre in mongo. Your entity class and repository class

Comment: Anyone can help me on this

Comment: Any idea on this